# index 20 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20

Tags: python, indexing, range

I am trying to create a function that has an array of zeros with a 1 at the center. Using randrange, the function decides where to add a count in the array with respect to the center. The new site will then be the new reference rather than the center. This should happen for m iterations. Once the array has a 1 in the first site, then the function should return the m value in which this occurred.

```py
def random_walk_mod(n,m):
    array = np.zeros(n) #create array of zeros of length n
    array[n//2] = 1
    start_pos = n//2
    for i in range(m):
        direction = randrange(-1,2,2) #get direction of left or right
        pos = start_pos + direction #Change position from center
        array[pos] = array[pos]+1 
        start_pos = pos

        if array[0] == 1:
            return i
```

However when calling the function more than once with

```py
for i in range(20):
    m = random_walk_mod(20,1000):
        print(m)
```

I get this error

```py
index 20 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20
```

Comment: index starts at 0 and ends at 19 for an iterable with a size of 20.

Comment: Your code generates values of `pos` that are outside the array index range (between 0 and 19).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue come from this line.

```
pos = start_pos + direction
```

Your direction can be 1 or - 1, but if it's 10 time 1, as your exemple start with 20, you will get 20 // 2 + 10 = 20. As you have create an array with 20 value, index 20 does not exist.

Now you can catch it with a try/except block or you can add another condition to check if 1 is at the end of your array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a stopper for the right side of the array to prevent to going out of range. This should work:

```
 def random_walk_mod(n,m):
    array = np.zeros(n) #create array of zeros of length n
    array[n//2] = 1
    start_pos = n//2
    for i in range(m):
        direction = random.randrange(-1,2,2) #get direction of left or right
        pos = start_pos + direction #Change position from center

        array[pos] = array[pos]+1 
        start_pos = pos
        if array[0] == 1:
            return i
        if array[n-1] == 1: #This code will prevent your index for going to far on the right
            return i
```